# Get the first empty column of the row.... then log that cell's row + column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am new to javascript and scrip editor. I've gotten pretty far by explaining the logic to myself and breaking things down step by step. But there is one last part of the puzzle that I can't seem to solve. I would like for script to **go to the first empty column** of row 16 and give me the row + column of that particular cell. All of the code works, however, what is happening when it gets to step 5 of the script, is that **it is placing "it worked" in the last empty column of the row, instead of the first**.

[image]

```
​​function refreshCell(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14FgHQieAOCko3pwzLSUnO5Ky5EuLN88r5Y4LnuMKREI");
  var sheetName = app.getSheetByName("FinancialGoals");
  var cellContainingFormula = sheetName.getRange("J14");

  /* 1. Clear cell containing formula */
  cellContainingFormula.clear();

  /* 2. auto-run functon refreshCell on the first of the month: edit > project triggers > add new trigger */

  /* 3. Add new formula to cell */
  cellContainingFormula.setValue('=10248-A16');

  /* 4. Add formatting to cell: set background color, textcolor green, text bold, center text */ 
 cellContainingFormula.setBackground('#B7B7B7').setFontColor('#38761d').setHorizontalAlignment('center');

  /* 5. Navigate to the first empty column of row */
   var lastColumn = sheetName.getLastColumn();
   var activeCell = sheetName.getRange(16, lastColumn).activate(); 
   activeCell.setValue("it worked")
}
```

Comment: You say `/* 5. Navigate to the first empty column of row */`   and `I would like for script to go to the first empty column of row 16` also `is that it is placing "it worked" in the last empty column of the row, instead of the first.` not sure what mean.  How about a picture.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had attached one, a screenshot is there now 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function refreshCell(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("FinancialGoals");
  var cellContainingFormula=sh.getRange("J14");
  cellContainingFormula.clear();
  cellContainingFormula.setValue('=10248-A16');
  cellContainingFormula.setBackground('#B7B7B7').setFontColor('#38761d').setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  var col=sh.getRange(16,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].reduce(function(a,c,i){if(c=='' && !a.found) {a.col=i+1;a.found=true;}return a;},{col:0,found:false}).col;
  sh.getRange(16,col).setValue("it worked");
}
```

Comment: AHHHHHHHH it worked it worked it worked! Thanks so much Cooper! It now places any new data in the next empty cell of that row. Okay I am off to google now to off to attempt and explain to myself why that code worked, lol that second to last line of code is.... not familiar. Thank you so much for your help on this!

Comment: The reduce method is very useful.  As a hint consider that in this case the accumulator is initialized to an object.